# Using multiple Dataframe Methods at once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is stacking up pandas dataframe mehtods an issue? I always use methods in a consecutive manner like df.sort_value().dropna().unstack().reset_index() etc

However, I just figured out that this right here leads to an empty/deleted dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [4, 3]})
df = df.sort_values(by=['col2']).to_excel('TestOut.xlsx')
print(df)
```

Out: None

Furthermore, I am also wondering right now, are consecutive methods processed from left to right?

Comment: `to_excel` doesn't output anything, it is not chainable

Comment: to_excel return `None` and write data to file, it is correct ouput.

Comment: `leads to an empty/deleted dataframe` - dont worry, dataframe is not empty/ deleted.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the enlightenment. df = df.to_excel() sets my dataframe to the return value from the to_excel(). However, how do I find out if methods are chainaible / the return value? Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) doesn't output anything, this is **not** a chainable method.

You need to separate the export part:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [4, 3]})
df = df.sort_values(by=['col2'])
print(df)
df.to_excel('TestOut.xlsx')
```

To know is a method is chainable, read the docs, **does it have an output as Series/DataFrame**?

`to_excel` does not so **it is not chainable**, [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) (for example) returns a DataFrame, so **it is chainable**, except when used with `inplace=True`.

Documentation from `reset_index`:

> Returns:  DataFrame or None
>
> DataFrame with the new index or None if inplace=True.